# Axios isn't sending session data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I've developed an app using React, Mongodb, Node, and Express and i'm using sessions for authentication. On the backend, I can successfully set a cookie a store a userID however when I try to make requests from the react app using axios, the userID session data is not sent.

This is my session config on the backend:

```
app.use(session({
      name: SESS_NAME || "***",
      secret: SESS_SECRET || "***",
      saveUninitialized: false,
      resave: false,
      store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: db,
        collection: 'session',
        ttl: parseInt(SESS_LIFETIME) / 1000 || (60 * 60 * 48) / 1000
      }),
      cookie: {
        sameSite: true,
        path: '/',
        domain: APP_DOMAIN || 'localhost:4000',
        secure: false, //NODE_ENV === 'production',
        maxAge: parseInt(SESS_LIFETIME) || 60 * 60 * 48
      }
    }));
```

My cors is configured as follows:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4000");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  next();
});
const corsConfig = {
    origin:['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:4000' ],
    methods:['GET','POST'],
    credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsConfig));
```

after logging in I set the userID in my user Routes, which I confirmed is set by console logging:

```
req.session.userId = user._id;
```

This is an example request from my react app

```
axios.get('/user/auth', { withCredentials: true })
        .then(response => {
          ...
```

Note that my app is being served on the same domain - I'm using the node app to serve the react app. my folder structure is similar to the following

```
 - APP PARENT FOLDER
   -CLIENT //Whole react app
   -MODELS
   -ROUTES
   -SERVER.JS
   -PACKAGE.JSON
   -NODE_MODULES
```

I have searched everywhere and tried everything I can think of... no luck. I would appreciate any help!

I've already checked articles on stack overflow and tried to implement the fixes but have had no luck. I've tried the following fixes:

```
// in my index.js file
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

and adding

```
{ withCredentials: true }
```

to all of my requests

When I take the userid created at login (ex: 5d6b5d2b09f7d1332543ba90) and manually plug this into the user Route on the backend then everything works fine.

When I console log the session on every request made by the react app it looks like this:

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-09-05T05:38:09.657Z,
     originalMaxAge: 172800,
     httpOnly: true,
     sameSite: true,
     domain: 'localhost:4000',
     secure: false },
 }
```

When it should look like this:

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-09-05T05:38:09.657Z,
     originalMaxAge: 172800,
     httpOnly: true,
     sameSite: true,
     domain: 'localhost:4000',
     secure: false },
  userId: 5d6b5c2b03f7d5532543ba90 }
```

Comment: Are third party cookies enabled in your browser?

Comment: @Ferrybig yes they are enabled.. I've tried multiple browsers too

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having exactly the same problem right now with React Native. The only way it works is by sending `{ withCredentials: true }`. However we were sending `false` previously and we didn't have any issues  which makes me think that the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Update on my previous comment:
We were using axios `0.19.0` and that version works just fine, however after upgrading to the latest (0.19.2 at the moment), the `userId` stopped being included in the session object. 
Fixing the version to 0.19.0 solved the problem for me 